# My mesh is pink in weight painting

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

I am trying to weight paint my rigged character (rigify add on used). But it is completely pink when i select the custom shapes. But I can see weights when i click on individual vertex group. Also when trying to paint using vertex group selection, I can only paint it to a value, not to 0?? Did I do something wrong?

On further playing around I found, for some reason when i select my custom shapes, it does not select the corresponding deform bone, unless i select it manually from the vertex group box, and then my weight painting tool doesnt work on it either. I have attached my blend file:

https://ufile.io/6wpqa

Answer (score 2):

The weight paint pink color tells you that you are trying to assign weight relatively to a bone which has no vertex group assopciated, because it's a non-deforming bone: all rigify rig works in a way in which the controllers bones are different than the deforming bones.

[image]

If you want to assign weight controlled by the "head" bone you will have to check the "deforming" option and create a vertex group with the same exact name.

[image]